# Mux .aac and .h265 together using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, h.265

I found some example codes on the internet and built a program to encode a live feed from a webcam or yuv file using h265. I used the libx265 for this with ffmpeg.

Now i want to mux an aac file with the produced h265 file and make a mp4. Can anyone suggest me a coding sample for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i inputvideofile -i inputaudiofile -map 0:v -map 1:a -codec copy -shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: `-strict -2` is only necessary when encoding.

Comment: @slhck - edited.